# Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind Identity

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, rational-functions, elliptic-integrals

Is there an identity for $\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}=?$ where $K(k)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(x)}}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}dt$ is the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind and $K'(k)=K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$ ? The closest I got was showing that $$1.):\frac{K'(k)}{K(\frac{1-k}{1+k})}=\frac{2}{1+k}$$  and from the book "Pi and the AGM" i got an identity showing $$2.):\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}=2\frac{K'(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k})}{K(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k})}$$ however this identity isn't particularly useful for me. Is there a identity that is similar to the identity I derived for $1.)$

Comment: The identity you suggested isn't useful for me because it simplifies to $$\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}=\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}$$ I was hoping for a rational expression in terms of k or a series similar to example 1.) that I gave in my question.

Comment: $$ K(k)=\frac{\pi}{2}\theta_3^2(q),\quad  q= e^{-\pi K'/K} $$ and special values for $K,K'$ are related to modular equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $\lim_{x\to0}$ $\frac{2\ln(\frac{4}{x})}{\pi}$ = $\frac{K'(x)}{K(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

The [OEIS sequence A227503](https://oeis.org/A227503) may be what you are looking for. By definition the
[Jacobi nome q](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nome.html) is $\, q = \exp(-\pi K'(k)/K(k))\,$ which implies
$\,K'(k)/K(k) = -\log{(q)}/\pi.\,$ This can be expanded as a power series in $\,k.\,$ The sequence A227503 is closely related to that series expansion.
$$ \frac{K'(k)}{K(k)} = -\frac1{\pi}\left(\log(x)+8\left(x + 13\, x^2/2 + 184\, x^3/3+\dots\right)\right) $$
where $\, x := k^2/16.\,$ and the coefficients are from OEIS A227503.

There are several other methods depending on your needs and you can choose among them.Read the [DLMF Chapter 19](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19) on Elliptic integrals for much more details. In particular, equations 19.5.5 and 19.5.6.

**P.S.** In your question you mention an identity from "Pi and the AGM".

Note that in the context of $\ q = \exp(-\pi K'(k)/K(k))\ $ that the map $\ k \to 2\sqrt{k}/(1+k)\ $ corresponds to $\ q \to \sqrt{q}\ $ and its inverse mapping 
$\ k \to (1-k')/(1+k')\ $ corresponds to $\ q \to q^2.\ $ These are known as ascending and descending transformations.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful and what I wanted. However is it possible it can be expressed as a rational expression?

Comment: Okay thanks a lot this is very helpful.

Comment: for my purposes I need more accuracy, is there a way to employ argument reduction for $\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}$ similar to how $\ln(\frac{x}{2^n})=\ln(x)-n*ln(2)$?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear with my question I did read it and understand that $j=\frac{1-k'}{1+k'}$ $$K(k)=(1+j)(K(j))$$ however since the series starts to diverge for $k$ around $1$ is there was a way to employ an argument reduction for $\frac{K'(\frac{k}{2})}{K(\frac{k}{2})}$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're asking for something like this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularEquation.html
Or this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral (look under complete elliptic integral of the first kind under "relation to Jacobi theta function")
The relation you derived can be used in the identity for the theta function to find the value of it when the imaginary part is equal to 2, and using some relationships between the other theta functions you can evaluate values of all the theta functions for all powers of 2, which allows you to calculate values of the j invariant for all powers of 2 as well (just thought that was interesting)

Comment: What I wanted was a relation such as example 1.) in my question. Something of a rational expression. I don't know if $l=\sqrt{1-k^2}$ satisfies the modular form.